# Composing function returning list and function taking multiple arguments

Tags: programming

What is the easiest way to compose a function that returns a list of $n$ elements with a function that takes $n$ arguments. If I know this $n$ a priori, I can do something like

```
{x1,...,xn} = f1[...];
f2[x1,...,xn]
```

where for $n=2$ this would be {x1,x2} = ... etc. Is there a way of accomplishing such a composition without having to introduce named variables? What about the case, where I don't know the $n$?

In other words, I'd like to somehow curry/uncurry functions on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example:

```
Apply[f2, f1[...]]
```

Or, in the Mathematica shorthand:

```
f2 @@ f1[...]
```

Comment: That was simple.

Answer (score 1):

More of a comment than an answer, because I suspect this trivial solution to your minimal working example does not get at the real question.  In any case, what is wrong with lists?

```
f1[list_] := list^2
f1 /@ {{a, b}, {c, d, e}}

(*{{a^2, b^2}, {c^2, d^2, e^2}}*)

f2[list_] := Plot[#[x], {x, 0, 2}] & /@ list
f2 /@ {{Sin, Cos, Log}, {# &, #^2 &}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct operations under discussion here: "argument spreading" and function composition.

We will define concrete examples of `f1` and `f2` for purposes of discussion:

```
f1[n_] := n ^ {0, 1, 2}

f2[x_, y_, z_] := x + y - z
```

So:

```
f1[3]
(* {1, 3, 9} *)

f2[1, 3, 9]
(* -5 *)
```

**Argument Spreading = *Apply***

`f1` returns a `List` of values, but the arguments to `f2` are a simple `Sequence`.  The required spreading of arguments is called "application" and is facilitated by [Apply](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) which has a short form `@@`:

```
f2 @@ f1[3]
(* -5 *)
```

Sometimes it is useful to curry a combination of explicit arguments and listed arguments.  An application of [Sequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) can be used for this purpose:

```
f2[1, Sequence @@ {3, 9}]
(* -5 *)
```

**Function Composition**

The preceding examples all involved actual function invocations.  Sometimes it is useful to take a more functional approach and combine functions prior to actually calling them.

For example, we could define `f3` that represents the desired combination of `f1` and `f2` using [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) notation like this:

```
f3 = f2 @@ f1[##] &

f3[3]
(* -5 *)
```

Version 10 introduced some nice new operator short forms.  It permits a definition like this:

```
f4 = Apply[f2] @* f1

f4[3]
(* -5 *)
```

`f4` is defined in so-called "point-free" style, where there is no mention of the arguments.

`@*` is the [left composition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) operator.  There is also a [right composition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html) operator, `/*`:

```
f5 = f1 /* Apply[f2]

f5[3]
(* -5 *)
```